# Accessing databases in C#/.NET without CodeFirst

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

This may be a bit silly, but all the applications I've built have always utilized the EF Code-First approach to generate the database.  When using this method, I've always accessed the database through the Context:

```
public class RandomController : Controller
{

    public CombosContext db = new CombosContext();

    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var rows = db.Combos.OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToList();
```

However, what if the database is already created for me, OR I create one by adding entities to the schema/design surface and then generate the database from that.  How would I access the db without the

```
public CombosContext db = new ComboxContext();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still do this with Code first and is the better approach IMHO. Use the Entity Framework Power Tools to reverse engineer your existing database into a code-first model.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d/

See my demo on using it at:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DEV215

Answer (score 2):

If the DB is already created, you can use the Database First approuch: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx

A basic setup would by to rightclick the project in the solution explorer and click Add > new item. On the dialog, select Data on the left pane and ADO.net Entity Data Model and follow the wizard to create your model based on the database. This way, you will have a context object exactly the way you have with code first (with some minor changes, but works almost the same).

Comment: Unless the EF model importer is a step up from the LINQ2SQL one I would highly recommend acquiring the Huagati tools if the schema is ever going to change ..